# c++ regex_replace not doing intended substitution

Tags: c++, regex

The following code is intended to convert the )9 in the first line to a )*9.
The original string is printed unmodified by the last line.

```
std::string ss ("1 + (3+2)9 - 2 ");
std::regex ee ("(\\)\\d)([^ ]");

std::string result;
std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), ss.begin(), ss.end(), ee, ")*$2");
std::cout << result;
```

This is based on a very similar example at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/

MS Visual Studio Express 2013.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: MS Visual Studio Express 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues: first, your capture group should only include the `'9'` portion of the string, and second the group you want to use for replacement is not $2, but $1:

```
std::string ss ("1 + (3+2)9 - 2 ");
static const std::regex ee ("\\)(\\d)");

std::string result;
std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), ss.begin(), ss.end(), ee, ")*$1");
std::cout << result;
```

Output:

> 1 + (3+2)*9 - 2

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/2mq4u3)

---

### Edit

It appears that you want a more general replacement.

That is, wherever there is a number followed by an open paren, e.g `1(` or a close paren followed by a number, e.g. `)1`. You want an asterisk between the number and the paren.

In C++ we can do this with `regex_replace`, but we need two of them at this time of writing. We can kind of chain them together:

```
std::string ss ("1 + 7(3+2)9 - 2");
static const std::regex ee ("\\)(\\d+)");
static const std::regex e2 ("(\\d+)\\(");

std::string result;
std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), ss.begin(), ss.end(), ee, ")*$1");
result = std::regex_replace (result, e2, "$1*(");
std::cout << result;
```

Output:

> 1 + 7*(3+2)*9 - 2

[Live Demo2](http://ideone.com/Ct8scY)

---

### Edit 2

Since you asked in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994372/c-regex-replace-d-s-with-d) how to turn this into one that can also capture spaces, here is a slight modification to handle possible spaces between the number and paren chars:

```
static const std::regex ee ("\\)\\s*(\\d+)");
static const std::regex e2 ("(\\d+)\\s*\\(");
```

[Live Demo3](http://ideone.com/K1vzPW)

Comment: Or a raw string literal: `R"(\)(\d))"`.

Comment: @T.C. Useful comment. So sick of all the double slashes for regex in C++

Comment: I need more than just the '9', as I need a general purpose function to put a '*' between any numbers and '(' or ')'.

Comment: @AndyG - I still get the orginal string running the Live Demo.  Changing it to $1 had no effect.  The original string, without the '*' added is still printed.

Comment: When I run this code in Live Demo (C++ 14) it works.  However, when I run identical code in MS Visual Studio Express 2013, the original string is printed out, without the '*'.

Comment: It literally took hours for VC++ 2013 to install itself.  (On a 2.2Ghz 8GB Ram laptop running Windows 8.0).   Please don't tell me I have to uninstall it and install an older one, assuming that's still available for free from MS.  I installed VC++ for this project...

Comment: @MikeSmith: See my edit. Perhaps Express doesn't properly support regex yet?

Comment: I just noticed you added "static const" to the code.  It works like that.  Thanks.

Comment: @MikeSmith: Is there something wrong with this answer now?