# c++ regex: replace \d\s( with \d*(

Tags: c++, regex

In the string ss, how do I replace `"3 ("` with `"3*("` ?
(It needs to work in general for any number.)

```
std::string result;
std::string ss;
static const std::regex nn1 ("\\)(\\d)");
static const std::regex nn2 ("(\\d)(\\s\\()");

ss = "5 + 3 (2 + 1)";
std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), ss.begin(), ss.end(), nn2, "\d*($2");
std::cout << result << "\n";
```

Compiler error line 7 - `'\d'` is an unrecognized escape sequence.
(I tried `'\\d'` there.)

MS Visual Studio 2013

(Not a dupe of the proposed question, as this deals with changing a character rather than inserting one, and this deals with the limitation that you can't use regular expressions in replacement strings, and have to work around that, which is solved in the selected answer by using $1 first.)

Comment: I have a general request: when you get help, please pay off with upvotes and accepted answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ regex\_replace not doing intended substitution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991889/c-regex-replace-not-doing-intended-substitution)

Comment: The dup I linked is your other, essentially identical question, Mike.

Comment: @AndyG: Now, the part of string to capture is different. Not sure if we should consider it as a duplicate.

Comment: @stribizhev: This question is a minor generalization of the question that was intended to be asked before.

Comment: It's a very different question, as this deals with changing a character rather than inserting a character, and you have to get around the limitation that you can't use regular expression patterns in replacement strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a more general way for such strings (but with one parenthesis) You can use following regex :

```
(\d)\s?\(
```

And replace with :

```
$1\*\(
```

`$1` will match the first group within your regex that is the digit before parenthesis.

Edit: and in c++ you can do:

```
std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), ss.begin(), ss.end(), nn2, "$1\*\(");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize you couldn't substitute with /d in c++, and you have to work around that.  This change works:
  std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), ss.begin(), ss.end(), nn2, "$1\\*\\(");

Comment: Also, I didn't need to change any other lines.

Comment: @MikeSmith Your're welcome! i added your suggestion! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Compiler error occurs because you are using an escape sequence `\d` inside a C++ string, that just does not exist. Worse, you are trying to use a regular expression pattern inside a replacement string, which is not what you want. You want to use some literal string in there, with back-references of type `$1` (`$` + `digit referring to the capturing group in a regex pattern`).

Use this code:

```
std::string result;
std::string ss;
static const std::regex nn1 ("\\)(\\d)");
static const std::regex nn2 ("(\\d+)\\s*\\(");

ss = "5 + 3 (2 + 1)";
std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), ss.begin(), ss.end(), nn2, "$1*(");
std::cout << result << "\n";
```

Output:

[image]

`nn2` variable will hold the regex `(\d+)\s*\(` that will capture

- `(\d+)` - Digits, 1 or more, but as many as possible, and will place in Group 1
- `\s*\(` - 0 or more spaces, and a literal opening round bracket

When replacing, we'll refer to the first group as `$1`. No need escaping `*` and `(`.

Comment: No, using a regular expression pattern in the replacement string is exactly what I wanted to do, but it appears you can't do that with c++ with that function, so you have to work around the limitation.  Thanks for your help. You answer does provide help, however, but the answer I selected is closer to what I was asking.

Comment: The answer you chose will fail in case you have more than 1 space between  `3` and `(`. Anyway, you can upvote to express gratitude on SO :) Just another "grudge": Kasra had `\1` in his original answer instead of `$1`, and after he saw my answer, he updated accordingly.

Comment: Okay.  You changed a lot of things.  I don't need d+, and I don't need s*, as there will always only be one space with this problem spec.  Anyway, I have enough votes to upvote now, so I did, as your answer does contain the solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Also, please consider accepting my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992601 so that the question is "finalized".

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    ResultString = TRegEx::Replace(SubjectString, "\"(\\d+) \\(\"", "\"$1*(\"", TRegExOptions() << roSingleLine << roMultiLine);
} catch (ERegularExpressionError *ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Regex Explanation:

```
"(\d+) \("

Options:  Exact spacing; Dot matches line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks; Numbered capture

Match the character “"” literally «"»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\d+)»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “ ” literally « »
Match the character “(” literally «\(»
Match the character “"” literally «"»

"$1*("

Insert the character “"” literally «"»
Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1 «$1»
Insert the character string “*("” literally «*("»
```